# Including HTML in JSF resource bundle string - possible?

Tags: html, jsf, properties, resourcebundle

I am using a property defined in a resource bundle properties file in an `h:outputText` tag in my JSF page.  Is it possible to include HTML in the property file string, so that I can display an image on the page?  The reason that I can't do this directly in the page is that this has to be a configurable option for the operations team.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just set `escape="false"` on the `<h:outputText>` so that the value won't be HTML-escaped.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle['some.key']}" escape="false" />
```